# Which one of the two NSTextViews has been edited? doCommandBySelector is always returns the first one

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I'm desperate to find the answer, so I opened TextLayoutDemo sample project from Apple. The point is that: I have two NSTextViews for column view. Everything works fine, text I enter is successfully laying out in those two text views via single layout manager:

```
    NSLayoutManager *twoColumnLayoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];

    NSTextContainer *firstColumnTextContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] init];
    NSTextContainer *secondColumnTextContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] init];

    NSTextView *firstColumnTextView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 240, 360) textContainer:firstColumnTextContainer];
    firstColumnTextView.delegate = self;
    NSTextView *secondColumnTextView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(240, 0, 240, 360) textContainer:secondColumnTextContainer];
    secondColumnTextView.delegate = self;

    [firstColumnTextContainer setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(240, 360)];
    [secondColumnTextContainer setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(240, 360)];

    [twoColumnLayoutManager addTextContainer:firstColumnTextContainer];
    [twoColumnLayoutManager addTextContainer:secondColumnTextContainer];
    [twoColumnLayoutManager replaceTextStorage:[firstTextView textStorage]];

    [[secondWindow contentView] addSubview:firstColumnTextView];
    [[secondWindow contentView] addSubview:secondColumnTextView];
```

But my goal is to get to know in which one text views the user edits a text. If it's the left one, I need to call one method, but if it's the right one, I want to call another method. And it seems impossible to recognize the correct text view, because delegate always get notified by the first text view.

```
- (BOOL) textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector {
    NSLog(@"edit: %@", textView);
    return NO;
}
```

This method is always prints the first text view, even if I change text in the second one. And I see it's going according to docs, where Apple says there always will be just the first NSTextView in series.

But how can I solve my problem then?

Comment: Of course...  You are not telling the last method which textview you are referring to.

Comment: How exactly? As I understand, a text view which has been edited calls this method of its delegate to tell exactly where the command takes places. Am I wrong? So, the (NSTextView *)textView has to be different depending on where the action takes place.

Comment: I suggest you read every single topic involving NSTextView.  I won't give out a solution very easily.

Comment: I really did. And several time have red the Apple docs. And I still can't find any clue.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell me, if this solution is the one I am looking for. Because, in fact, it works just fine. The one thing I don't understand is why Cocoa text system is so tricky where it is not necessary?

```
- (void)textStorageDidProcessEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // that's the active text view
    NSWindow *keyWindow = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    NSTextView *activeTextView = (NSTextView *)[keyWindow firstResponder];
    NSLog(@"%p", activeTextView);
}
```

UPDATE: this works only if user clicked the mouse button. Arrow keys do not update window's first responder:(